# Is bondage permissible during sexual activities in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, husband-wife

> Bondage - sexual practice that involves the tying up or restraining of one partner.

During sexual intercourse or other such sexual activities, is it permissible to indulge in bondage if it pleases both partners?

Comment: Why should it be haram?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find anything directly against bondage *per se*.  There's fatawa like the following, where it's not the bondage but other aspects which are problematic:

> Moreover, Allah SWT has honored the Children of Adam and many of these practices are bizarre and contradict such honoring as well as human dignity. A Muslim has to keep such criteria in his mind to decide which of these practices is permissible and which is not.
> <sub>Muhammad Salama, [AboutIslam](http://aboutislam.net/live-session/live-fatwa-general-session-3/bdsm-phenomena/)</sub>

The fatwa above is about BDSM in general, which is broad, and includes inappropriate things (perhaps [needle play](http://bdsmwiki.info/Needle_Play)).

Here's two fatwa which describe it as permissible (to some extent):

> If the husband and wife mutually agree on "BDSM", that is their choice, for which there is no prohibition in Shariah.
> <sub>Mufti Ebrahim Desai, [AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/4398.html)</sub>
>
> The wife does not have to obey unreasonable sexual requests such as bondage or the use of sex toys. If she decides to agree to such matters— in a way that is not physically, emotionally, or relationally harmful nor demeaning or unbecoming of Allah's  honoring of humans— then this is purely her own decision, and the husband does not have the right to "demand" such matters. 
> <sub>Faraz Rabbani, SunniPath Academy Teacher, sourced from [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/FatawaBatch1IntimacyUpdate2008September/Fatawa%20-%20Batch%201-%20Intimacy%20Update%202008%20September_djvu.txt)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As long as both the wife and husband agree to it. The husband must not do anything without his wife consenting first. Also, it it is harmful in any way physically, emotionally, mentally then you shouldn't do it. Enjoy the BDSM :)